# What concept did pre-modern people have about thermodynamic phenomena?

Tags: physics, thermodynamics

How did people before the advent of modern science in the 17th century conceive thermodynamic phenomena? I want to know how people in Ancient Mesopotamia, Egypt, Greece, Rome, China and in the Middle Ages thought about temperature, heat, pressure, melting point, and the phase transitions between solid, liquid and gas, given that they are commonly observed phenomena, relevant in our daily lives.

Comment: You need more focus.  That's an enormous range of time and space.  For instance, one pre-Socratic philosopher proved that air existed because water will stop flowing out of a gourd if you stopped the hole by which air flowed in.  They thought differently before and after.

Comment: The same concept "modern" laymen may have.

Comment: Please choose a more narrow region and time period.

Comment: One could consider https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fan_death as a modern misconception about thermodynamic phenomena.